# expiresIn not working in jsonwebtoken.sign() even with object literal

Tags: javascript, jwt, object-literal

Here is my code, as you can see, [I am using an object literal as suggested in the jsonwebtoken library help](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwtsignpayload-secretorprivatekey-options-callback), but the result is always the same

```
  const TOKEN = {
    JWT: JWT.sign({
      iat: Date.now(),
      data: {
        username: USER.name,
        userLevel: USER.level,
        userId: USER._id,
        limit: USER.limit,
        has2FA: USER.has2FA
      }
    }, SECRET_KEY,
    { expiresIn: 60 * 60 * 12 }
    )
  }
```

As you can see, this code returns both the iat and exp with just a few minutes and seconds of difference instead of the 12 hours that I want.

Any ideas on why is this happening?

[image]

---

**Edit**: I am using jsonwebtoken and Dayjs to display the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the fact that you are specifying `iat` in *milliseconds* whereas it's expected to be in *seconds*. So either do

```
iat: Date.now()/1000,
```

or completely remove that property because that's the default value anyway.